# Automate process of creating new apps in Branch.io

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, branch.io

Is it possible to automate the process of creating and setting up branch io for multiple apps? I have a multi-tenant architecture and want to automate this process for every new app.

These are the steps that I need to automate from Branch.io dashboard:

1. Create New App
2. Configure require redirects (I see [this](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/deep-linking-api#endpoint---update-app-config) provides enough)
3. Get default/alternate link domains

So for #1 and #3 I did not find anything related into Branch.io API docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to automate the process of creating new applications would be to use our App Creation API. Currently it is not available as we are revamping it. The only way you can create apps is currently through the Dashboard itself.

If you want to know more details and specifics regarding this please reach out to our [Support team](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/page/submit-a-ticket).